# Accordance of linkage between declaration and definition

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

I am wondering if the C snippet below, in which the definition of `f` fails to repeat that `f` is of `static` linkage, is correct:

```
static int f(int);

int f(int x) { return x; }
```

Clang does not emit any warning for it. I read clause 6.7.1 of the C11 standard without finding the answer to my question.

It is possible to imagine more questions along the same vein, for instance t1.c and t2.c below, and it would be nice if an answer was general enough to apply to some of these, but I am only really concerned about the first example above.

```
~ $ cat t1.c
static int f(int);

int f(int);

int f(int x) { return x; }
~ $ clang -c -std=c99 -pedantic t1.c
~ $ nm t1.o
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/…/bin/nm: no name list
~ $ cat t2.c
int f(int);

static int f(int);

int f(int x) { return x; }
~ $ clang -c -std=c99 -pedantic t2.c
t2.c:3:12: error: static declaration of 'f' follows non-static declaration
static int f(int);
           ^
t2.c:1:5: note: previous declaration is here
int f(int);
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules for linkage are a little confusing, and it is different for functions and objects. In short, the rules are as follows:

- The first declaration determines the linkage.
- `static` means internal linkage.
- `extern` means linkage as already declared, if none is declared, external.
- If neither of them is given, it’s the same as `extern` for functions, and external linkage for object identifiers (with a definition in the same translation unit).

So, this is valid:

```
static int f(int); // Linkage of f is internal.

int f(int); // Same as next line.

extern int f(int); // Linkage as declared before, thus internal.

int f(int x) { return x; }
```

This, on the other hand, is undefined behaviour (cf. C11 (n1570) 6.2.2 p7):

```
int f(int); // Same as if extern was given, no declaration visible,
            // so linkage is external.

static int f(int); // UB, already declared with external linkage.

int f(int x) { return x; } // Would be fine if either of the above
                           // declarations was removed.
```

Most of this is covered in C11 6.2.2. From the N1570 draft:

> (3) If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage. <sup>30)</sup>
>
> (4) For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible<sup>31)</sup>, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.
>
> (5) If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.
>
> <sup>30)</sup> A function declaration can contain the storage-class specifier static only if it is at file scope; see 6.7.1.
> <sup>31)</sup> As specified in 6.2.1, the later declaration might hide the prior declaration.

Comment: I don't see why the second snippet requires a diagnostic. In the contrary from what @BlueMoon cites, it seems that this "only" is UB.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thanks, I was wondering, how the UB mentioned in Blue Moon's answer should happen at all if it was a constraint violation, and that's the answer. Is my understanding correct, that usually, refusing to compile on UB (in a statement) means, the compiler must be able to determine that the code in question is reachable, but that doesn't apply here, because we're dealing with (file-scope) declarations?

Comment: Yes, here this is code that is not executed so reachability makes not much sense :) UB here means that the whole program has UB from the start. Probably basically because linking of the identifiers may have gone wrong. Still, having that as UB is kind of lame, this is easily detectable at compile time, so a constraint violation would be in order, I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thanks. The [C89 rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c1.html#3-1-2-2) has something to say about this, maybe the reason of the UB is to allow extensions/less changes in existing implementations without requiring a diagnostic for implementations where this has got some well-defined meaning (whatever this should be) and relying on implementors being sophisticated enough to abort compilation if it hasn't instead of formatting the hard-drive...

Answer (score 5):

According to *C11, 6.2.2, 7* they are all *undefined behaviours*.

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both
>   internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

A function is also an *identifier* and a function by default (without any qualifier like *static*) has external linkage.

**C11, 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**

> 1 An identifier can denote an object; a function; a tag or a member of a structure, union, or enumeration; a
>   typedef name; a label name; a macro name; or a macro parameter. The
>   same identifier can denote different entities at different points in
>   the program. A member of an enumeration is called an enumeration
>   constant. Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further
>   here, because prior to the semantic phase of program translation any
>   occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the
>   preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions.

Comment: Sorry, I am moving the “accepted” tag to another answer that better matches Clang's behavior. I remain thankful for you to have quickly pointed out that the explanation was to be found in 6.2.2.

Comment: np, it's your choice. I do agree mafso's better as it covers an additional difference when the order of declaration matters (and +1 to mafso!).